# MySQL create view based on child table status condition check

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Table: **tasks** (parent)

`id | name | ...(other columns)`

Table: **task_histories** (child)

`id | task_id(fk) | date | status(PENDING,OVERDUE,COMPLETE) | ...(other columns)`

The child table have multiple entries for the parent based on different dates.

I want to create a view `task_status_view` with `task_id | current_status` based on the below condition checks for till today's date comparison. (There should be only one entry for each `task.id`)

- IF: there is any entry with `status = 'OVERDUE'` then consider the `current_status` as `'O'`
- ELSE IF: there is any entry with `status = 'PENDING'` then consider the `current_status` as `'P'`
- ELSE: if any of above then consider the `current_status` as `'COMPLETE'`

Comment: Did you try case ?

Comment: i am making sql queries but can't even execute group by for one entry per task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called conditional aggregation.

```
select
  task_id,
  case
    when sum(status = 'OVERDUE') > 0 then 'OVERDUE'
    when sum(status = 'PENDING') > 0 then 'PENDING'
    else                                  'COMPLETE'
  end as total_status
from task_histories
group by task_id
order by task_id;
```

(In MySQL true equals 1 and false equals 0, so we can just add up conditions.)

Comment: thanks... i think it should work. but let me test all cases. can you add the `create view` syntax for the same?

Comment: No need further; i have created view based on this thanks..

Comment: You are welcome :-) If you want to incude tasks that have not started, you will have to select from the tasks table and outer join histories by the way.